# Pageviewcontroller is not showing page turn animation in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, uipageviewcontroller

I have build an iPad application based on pageviewcontroller, which contains images and text on each page. Its a simple application.

I have disable the tab on pages. I am only allowing swipe to turn page using this code

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers; 
UIGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = nil;
for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ( [recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] ) {
        tapRecognizer = recognizer;
        break;
    }
}

if ( tapRecognizer ) {
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [self.pageViewController.view removeGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

I have also disabled the landscap mode. The app only support Portrait mode.

Everything is working fine, the only issue i am having is that the app is not showing page turn animation on IOS 6. it just replace the page view when you swipe with no animation. But the app is working fine and showing all page turn and page back animations version lower than ios 6.

one more thing i have notice that when i swipe towards right (page back) i can see animation but while animation when i start swiping and stop in middle of screen and hold the page start turning with my finger and stop animation in middle as my finger stop but the app already removed my previous page view and showing me empty bg screen in back. And when i swipe towards left (page forward) app is not showing animation as i moved my finger but when i start mt finger it replace the view with next page view and when i finished swiping left after that app call pageViewController: didFinishAnimating: , that means its doing animation but not showing it.

Please help :(

Comment: sometimes getting this message Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DataViewController: 0x1f881170>. while turning page forward.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when navigating programmatically sometimes i get 'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DataViewController: 0x32fcd532>' and after some research i found that this message indicates that a new transition begins while the previous isn't completed yet.
i solved that by navigating without animation.